Do all magnetic monopole models always imply higher symmetry than regular EM?
(Isn't this question asked anywhere before)
First, Maxwell equations do not say that magnetic monopoles do not exist. The equations can easily be generalized to include magnetic monopoles.
What I want to know is. Do ALL magnetic monopole theories, models or ways how they interact with the default gauge theory of electromagnetism always imply higher symmetry gauge group? Or is there a model or interaction where monopoles don't need to have higher symmetry at all than regular EM or  not related to a higher symmetry (or not related to any concept of symmetry at all)?
